# css arrow of active LI with body image background?

Tags: html, css

My objective is to hide the line below the triangle to have this outcome _____^_____ on my active menu. 
    There are similar questions here at stackoverflow but those solutions doesn't fixed the issue I currently have. Pls help me play with it. Thanks!
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L786rqfs/) here.

```css
body {
    background: #1abc9c url(//dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/homepage/banner--themeforest-342995208860d6c90b98134db089ef84.jpg);
}
ul {
    width:100%;
    border-bottom:3px solid red
}
li {
    display:inline-block;padding:20px;
}
li a {
    display:block;position:relative;
}
li.active a:after {
    content:"";
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:12px auto 0;
    border:solid red;
    border-width:3px 3px 0 0;  
    -moz-transform:rotate(315deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(315deg);
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">LINK1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK2</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">LINK3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LINK4</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This CSS code will fix it:

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L786rqfs/6/

You need to bring the border to the LI and chop it in a left and right side in the before and after content. For the finishing touch I bring also the border to UL after content so you keep it 100% over the page.

```
body {
    background: #1abc9c url(//dmypbau5frl9g.cloudfront.net/assets/homepage/banner--themeforest-342995208860d6c90b98134db089ef84.jpg);
}

ul {
    overflow: hidden; /* Clear float and hide ul:after content overflow */
    position: relative; /* Relative for ul:after content */
    width: 100%;
}

ul:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute; /* Now it will start after the last LI */
    width: 100%;
}

li {    
    float: left;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

li:before,
li:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 3px solid red;    
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
}

li:before {
    left: 0;
}

li:after {
    right: 0;
}

li.active:before,
li.active:after {
    width: calc(50% - 8px); /* Transparent part of the arrow */
}

li a {    
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

li.active a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    border: solid red;
    border-width: 3px 3px 0;  
    -moz-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, a few words of explanation as to why this works would make it even better though.

Comment: nice one @Ben! I'll try to implement this. I should research about width: calc() too since it's my first time to hear it :D

Comment: You going to love the CSS calc function :) I use it to create the gap for the arrow. https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: @Ben: really a neat solution ... I've been thinking about this some time and have not been come to a clou. Thanks for sharing the link too.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom part of the triangle is from your `ul` menu `border-bottom: red 3px solid;` property and not from the `after`element.

You can try disguising the appearance by adding a background color close to your page's color like this:

```
li.active a:after {
  background-color: rgb(28, 183, 152);
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle of how it'll look like: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/L786rqfs/3/

Comment: Thanks @Andrew but my background is dynamic.

Comment: ..and also I have background with gradient, so I'm looking for other solution than this.